# Why doesn't my code return the word with the most characters?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, function, loops

I am trying to get JS to get the word with the most characters but for some reason my code always returns "The"

I have tried two variants of the code.

Variant 1:

```
let sent = "The quick borwn fox jumped over the jazy dog";
let word = findWord(sent);

function findWord(sent){

  splitSent=sent.split(" ");

  let largest="";

  for(i=0; i<splitSent.length;i++){

    if(splitSent[i].length>largest){

        largest=splitSent[i];
    }

  }

return largest;
}

console.log(word)
```

Variant 2:

```
let sent = "The quick borwn fox jumped over the jazy dog";
let word = findWord(sent);

function findWord(sent){

  splitSent=sent.split(" ");

  let largest="";

  for(split of splitSent){

    if(splitSent[i].length>largest){

        largest=splitSent[i];
    }

  }

return largest;

}

console.log(word)
```

the console just prints "The" from the first code and "fox" from the second

Comment: `largest` is a string, so `splitSent[i].length>largest` doesn't make sense, try comparing against `largest.length` instead. You should also consider avoiding implicitly creating global variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you need to check `largest.length` not `largest`.

```js
let sent = "The quick borwn fox jumped over the jazy dog";    
let word = findWord(sent);

    
function findWord(sent) {      
  splitSent = sent.split(" ");      
  let largest = "";      
  for (i = 0; i < splitSent.length; i++) {        
    if (splitSent[i].length > largest.length) {          
      largest = splitSent[i];        
    }      
  }      
  return largest;    
}

    
console.log(word);
```

Comment: No problem @snakeoilforcheap, if my answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Yeah I know, I have been waiting, there is a timed window before I can mark as solved.